# Show h is measurable

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:(X_1,B_1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $g:(X_2,B_2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ two measurables functions and consider the function $h:X_1 \times X_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $h(x_1, x_2)=f(x_1)g(x_2)$

Show $h$ is $B_1 \otimes B_2$ measurable

Do I need to use Fubini's Theorem to prove this? I'm confused
I was trying to guide myself through this exercise, but I don't know if it is similar [If $\nu_1 \ll \mu_1$ and $\nu_2 \ll \mu_2$ then $\nu_1 \otimes \nu_2 \ll \mu_1 \otimes \mu_2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105513/if-nu-1-ll-mu-1-and-nu-2-ll-mu-2-then-nu-1-otimes-nu-2-ll-mu-1?rq=1)

Any help will be grateful!!

Comment: Can you prove the statement if $f$ and $g$ are simple functions?

Comment: Yes, I did, but I don't know what else to do

Answer (score 1):

There are four parts to this proof.

Part 1: Prove that the multiplication function $\cdot : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable with respect to the $\otimes$ $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Proof: the $\otimes$-$\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is exactly the Borel sigma algebra. Since $\cdot$ is continuous, it is measurable.

Part 2: Show that given two measurable spaces $(A, S_A)$, $(B, S_B)$, the measurable space $(A \times B, S_A \otimes S_B)$ is the product of $A$ and $B$ in the category of measurable spaces.

Phrasing this in non-categorical terms, we must show that the projection functions $\pi_A : A \times B \to A$ and $\pi_B : A \times B \to B$ are measurable.

Then, show that given two measurable functions $f_A : C \to A$ and $f_B : C \to B$, the function $f : C \to A \times B$ defined by $f(c) = (f_A(c), f_B(c))$ is measurable.

Proof: left as an exercise. It follows fairly straightforwardly.

Part 3: Show that the composition of measurable functions is measurable.

Proof: left as an exercise. Very straightforward.

Part 4: Conclude that $h$ is measurable.

Proof: First, we consider the function $w : X_1 \times X_2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $w(x) = (f(\pi_1(x)), g(\pi_2(x))$. We note that $f \circ \pi_1$ is measurable, and we know that $g \circ \pi_2$ is measurable. Therefore, $w$ is measurable. Then, note that $h = \cdot \circ w$. Therefore, $h$ is measurable.